# Cannot convert value of type to expected argument type 'Bool'

Tags: swift

I am facing issue in Swift after converting from Objective-C. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

```
let brand: GymBrand =  GymBrand.brandForName(name:self.gym.brand)
if brand && brand.logoImageName {

} else {

}
```

My Objective-C code:

```
GYMBrand *brand = [GYMBrand brandForName:self.gym.brand];
if (brand && brand.logoImageName) {  

}else {

}
```

Error screen:

[image]

Comment: what do you want to say by saint if brand ?
The error clearly says it, you can only  write a bool variable or statement that produces a bool after if keyword

Comment: By using this if statement you are checking if `brand` is true however `brand` is not of type `Bool`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @UmairAfzal I have updated my Objective C code

Comment: how about adding a check like "brand != nil", that's going to be a bool check instead of directly checking brand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can do this : ( as i can see , you are using brand.logoImageName so you must use this way )

```
if let brand =  GymBrand.brandForName(name:self.gym.brand) as? GymBrand, let _ = brand.logoImageName as? String{
            //brand is never nil here
            //brand.logoImageName is never nil here
        } else {

        }
```

Comment: `as? String` (and most likely also `as? GymBrand`) is redundant if `logoImageName` is an optional anyway and `let _` is not helpful since the variable is clearly used in the `if` clause.

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is read about optionals in swift.

[Developer Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

[Tutorialpoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_optionals.htm)

These are some good references to read. There are 2 main ways to achieve what you want.

```
if let brand =  GymBrand.brandForName(name:self.gym.brand) ,

    let imageName = brand.logoImageName {

        //brand is never nil here
        //brand.logoImageName is never nil here
    } else {

    }
```

What we do here is we assume `GymBrand.brandForName(name:self.gym.brand)` could be a optional which mean it could hold nil values. By using if let we make sure that inside the if block the value of brand is never nil.

But lets say we want to use it not inside the block but in where ever in the function. Then we can use a `guard`.

```
guard let brand =  GymBrand.brandForName(name:self.gym.brand) ,let imageName = brand.logoImageName else {

        //brand is nil here
        //brand.logoImageName is nil here
    }
```

Comment: Even simpler: `if let imageName = GymBrand.brandForName(name:self.gym.brand)?.logoImageName { ...`

Answer (score 0):

The true face of your code in swift is this:

```
if let brand =  GymBrand.brandForName(name:self.gym.brand), brand.logoImageName != nil {

} else {

}
```

Comment: As `logoImageName` is going to be used in the `if` clause it's actually not *The true face of your code in swift* 